# Trying to use firebase test lab but Android Studio throws java.net.BindException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, google-cloud-test-lab, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to use the test lab from Android Studio but whenever I can see the following error when I try to make connection to the google cloud platform. I'm running it on Android Studio 2.1.1 and I'm on Mac

[image]

```
    java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
java.io.IOException: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at com.google.gct.login.CancellableServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(CancellableServerReceiver.java:97)
    at com.google.gct.login.GoogleLogin$AndroidUiFacade.obtainVerificationCodeFromExternalUserInteraction(GoogleLogin.java:606)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.common.GoogleLoginState.logInWithLocalServer(GoogleLoginState.java:334)
    at com.google.gct.login.GoogleLogin$1.run(GoogleLogin.java:341)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$14$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:634)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.gct.login.CancellableServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(CancellableServerReceiver.java:94)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?  That dialog for running tests looks old.  The latest Android Studio is 2.1.1 right now, and it has a slightly different UI.

Comment: I'm running it on 2.1.1 and I'm on Mac

Comment: That connect button is supposed to launch a Chrome tab to get you authenticated so that your Google account can be used from within Android Studio.  So try quitting both Studio and Chrome, then launch Chrome with a single window logged into your Google account.  Then launch Studio and see if it can connect.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work and I get the same error.

Comment: Rubin, I'm wondering if you're using a machine that blocks access to some ports or if you're using some sort of a Firewall? Are you able to reproduce the same issue on multiple laptops (other than your work laptop) in multiple network conditions?

Comment: This worked on other people's laptop who's on the same network as me. I'm not sure what the issue is but I don't have this laptop anymore.